# Geodesic cuffs of pairs of pants in a hyperbolic manifold- why are they disjoint?

Tags: 3-manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I'm trying to understand Kahn-Markovic's celebrated [Immersing almost geodesic surfaces in a closed hyperbolic three manifold](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5501). There is something probably quite basic which I can't figure out.

We have $M^3= \mathbb{H}^3/\mathcal{G}$ a closed hyperbolic $3$-manifold, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a Kleinian group. Let $\Pi^0$ be a topological pair of pants with cuffs $C_0$, $C_1$, and $C_2$, and let $\rho\colon\thinspace \pi_1(\Pi^0)\to \mathcal{G}\subset PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ be a faithful representation. Let $\gamma_i$ denote the geodesic in $M$ that represents the conjugacy class of $\rho(C_i)$ in $\mathcal{G}$ for $i=0,1,2$ (these become cuffs for pairs of pants which Kahn-Markovic construct inside $M$ and glue together to form an immersed almost geodesic surface).

> **Question**: Why are $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$, and $\gamma_2$ disjoint?

It is essential to the construction that the cuffs indeed be disjoint, because if they intersect, reduced complex Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates don't exist (there is no "foot"). In fact, Kahn and Markovic need many pairs of pants inside $M$ to coexist, so not understanding why the cuffs are non-intersecting even for a single pair of pants is particularly frustrating.

Comment: Dan, in general these geodesics intersect, just think about free subgroups in $PSL(2,R)$ uniformizing one-holed torus. 

Comment: +1 for the title itself!

Answer (score 6):

This is an extended comment:

As Misha says, the geodesics might be immersed in general, and in fact the pants and the surfaces they construct will in general be highly immersed (lots of self-intersections).

If you'd like to visualize embedded geodesics, you can imagine the lifts to the unit tangent bundle, or for a given pair of pants, it will lift to an embedded pants in some covering space corresponding to the image of the fundamental group $\rho(\pi_1(\Pi^0))$. To understand the feet of $\gamma_i$, then you can work in this covering space. The feet will be at the points of the shortest geodesics connecting the three boundary components in pairs (seams). There's a canonical involution sending $\gamma_i$ to its inverse, fixing the seams, and thus the feet lie equally spaced about each geodesic. Then project the whole picture back down into $M$ to get the feet.

Comment: One might also want to go all the way up to $\mathbb{H}^3$ and visualize the right-angled hexagons associated to $\rho(\pi_1(\Pi^0))$, although even in $\mathbb{H}^3$ there are cases where the hexagons degenerate to being non-embedded.

Comment: @ Lee: Yes, the cuffs of a general pants could intersect each other, although the cuffs will themselves be embedded. However, Kahn & Markovic make sure that the cuffs don't intersect, and in fact the pants are very close to being totally geodesic (this requires some careful estimates to make sure this happens). 

Comment: Where do Kahn and Markovic guarantee no intersections between cuffs? I'm looking at the construction of $\delta$ in Section 4.5. Thank you for the explanation of "feet" when there are intersections! 

Comment: @ Daniel: I think it's hidden in the statement of Theorem 3.1. The conditions on the pants guarantee that it's close to being totally geodesic, and therefore the cuffs don't intersect. 